# Magento custom options layout

Tags: xml, magento, layout, php

Can someone clearly explain to me how I get the custom options below the tabs?

I can not get it done. See link to the website:

http://tuinbeursshop.nl/40mm-blokhut-lean.html

You would help me a lot with it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to not rewrite html to tabs, but use CSS to display

elements as a block or to display as table cells. (blocks will be better)

```
<li class="options-list" style="display: block;">
<img style="display: block; float: left;" />
<span class="content" style="display: block; float right; width: 60%;">
Somethig as Dakshingles groen
</span>
<div style="clear: both;">don´t forget to clear!</div>
</li>
```